# Refresh page after bootstrap modal close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to refresh my current page after I close bootstrap modal.

```
$('#modal1').on('hide', function() {
window.location.href = 'current-page.php';
})
```

Is there a way for refresh current page after closing modal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can refresh current page after you close modal by this:

```
$('#modal1').on('hide', function() {
window.location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Refresh page using `location.reload();`

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
    location.reload();
});
```